# python pandas - filter multiple dataframe with single fieldname mask

Tags: python, pandas

Here is a sample code for filter: 2 `m` and 2 `dataframes`

```
m = (
    (dfeicsm.create_date.dt.floor('d') == '2019-09-14')

)
print dfeicsm[m].shape
m = (
    (dfeicsm_fids.create_date.dt.floor('d') == '2019-09-14')

)
print dfeicsm_fids[m].shape

(1090, 15)
(1133, 40)
```

Is there any possible way to do something like this.. Just an example.. one `m` for both dataframe. Assuming both dataframe have the same column names.. to keep it simplified.

```
m = (
    (create_date.dt.floor('d') == '2019-09-14')

)
print dfeicsm[m].shape
print dfeicsm_fids[m].shape

(1090, 15)
(1133, 40)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here number of columns is not important.

Generally it is possible only if same index values and also same values of column `create_date` between both - then masks are same and is possible reuse it.

But if different lengths or different values in datetime column then need filter separately.

Comment: do you think it is really an useful need for pandas to have a single `m` for both dataframe to make our lives even easier.. and technically in future it may become possible through some "simple" hack.

Comment: it is really a pain to copy as many `m` AND `dataframes[m]` for this for some of my projects.. in my question i have only kept it simple.. but i hope you can imagine.. multiple copy pastes for different frames.. with same `m` condition.

Comment: @ihightower one solution should be here, if not many large daraframes. Create dictionary of dataframes and also dictionary of masks in list comprehension. It is possible for you?

Comment: i can't imagine how that will work. but sounds to me more complicated than taking the easy route of the default solution of multiple copies (as in my question). but if you think your suggestion is simpler, please show me. hope my head will not spin. also about the large dataframe.. yes it may be large with 100,000rows each for example. i prefer a solution that works simply if possible. if not, then i will stick with default non fancy method. i wrote the question just to really make sure i was not missing the obvious.